# Entity framework core load navigation properties for recursive table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0 and the following model:

[image: Model]

So a Job has a MainFlow, and the mainflow can have 0 or more Subflows which in turn can have subflows (recursive)

The way this has been setup is that I have a Job entity which has a MainflowId property (and also navigation property)

The Flows have a ParentFlowId property, and a navigation property with a collection of SubFlows.

I also included a TreeId property on Job and Flow to easily identify a tree.

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp {get; set; }

    public string JobName{ get; set; }

    public int MainFlowId { get; set; }        

    public Guid TreeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Flow MainFlow { get; set; }
 }

public class Flow
{
    public int Id { get;set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public Guid TreeId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentFlowId { get; set; }                

    public virtual Flow ParentFlow { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Flow> SubFlows { get; set; } = new List<Flow>();
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to load a list of jobs (for example based upon the timestamp), but in a way that all the navigation properties become available (Job->Mainflow->Subflow->Subflow->...)

I was able to get this behavior by loading the jobs, and then loading the flows separately using the TreeId, however because of performance issues I am now using .AsNoTracking() and this does not seem to work anymore.

Is there a way to load the whole trees with their navigation properties while using .AsNoTracking?

Thanks for any insight!

Edit:
Here is the way it is working without the AsNoTracking()
(I simplified the code a bit)

```cs
private IQueryable<Job> GetAllJobs()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Job>()
        .Include(a=>a.MainFlow)
}

private IEnumerable<Flow> GetAllFlowsForTreeIds(IEnumerable<Guid> treeIds)
{
    var result = from flow in DbContext.Set<Flow>()
                    .Include(a => a.ParentFlow)
                    .AsEnumerable()
              join treeId in treeIds
              on flow.TreeId equals treeId
              select flow;
    
    return result;
}
```

```
public IEnumerable GetJobTrees()
{
    var allJobs = GetAllJobs().ToList();
    var flows = GetAllFlowsForTreeIds(allJobs.Select(a=>a.TreeId)).ToList());

    //by getting the flows, the navigation properties in alljobs become available
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a recursive query for this, can you provide the query you use right now?

Comment: @TimMG Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question with the code